# Converting an object T into a List<T> in C#

Tags: c#, .net, generics, collections, casting

I have a stupid yet braincracker issue about casting types. As you can see from the code I have a variable **lprod_monthylReport** that depending on the **ytm** value can be a `List<Monthly_Report>` or simply a `Monthly_Report`. I need the variable to have the same name in both cases.

```
var lprod_monthlyReport = new List<Monthly_Report>;

if (ytm == true)
{
   lprod_monthlyReport = _ProductRep.GetSpecificArchiveReport(prod.Prod_ID, lmonth, lyear, item.item_ID);
}
else
   lprod_monthlyReport = _ProductRep.GetSpecificYTMReport(prod.Prod_ID, item.item_ID);
```

The problem is that if I declare the variable inside each if (or else) section the compilers gives error because it says that the variable is already declared in this context.

I already tried casting

```
lprod_monthlyReport = (Monthly_Report) _ProductRep.GetSpecificArchiveReport(prod.Prod_ID, lmonth, lyear, item.Item_ID);
```

But it does not work. I also tried the **as** keyword without success.

May you please help me with this one? Thanks

Francesco

Comment: what type does GetSpecificArchiveReport and GetSpecificYTMReport return

Comment: Why does `lprod_monthlyReport` **have** to be a `List<Monthly_Report>`, rather than whatever your methods return?

Comment: @Hath: thanks for your answer. **GetSpecificArchiveReport** returns a **Monthly_Report** object (it makes a LINQ query using **Single**) **GetSpecificYTMReport** returns a **List<Monthly_Report>** (LINQ query using **Where**).

Comment: @Rowland Shaw: thanks for your answer. Notice that the two methods are different, not just the signature

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:
in case you've got a `Monthly_Report` just add it to the list...

```
    List<Monthly_Report> lprod_monthlyReport;
    if (ytm == true)
    {
       lprod_monthlyReport  = new List<Monthly_Report>();
       lprod_monthlyReport.add(_ProductRep.GetSpecificArchiveReport(prod.Prod_ID, lmonth, lyear, item.item_ID));
    }
    else{
       lprod_monthlyReport = _ProductRep.GetSpecificYTMReport(prod.Prod_ID, item.item_ID));
    }
```

Comment: Genious, that's what I was looking for! Many thanks. Actually I wanted to make a small improvement. You can declare at the beginning **var lprod_monthlyReport = new List<Monthly_Report>();** and take it out from the **if** block. Otherwise the **else** block won't work

Comment: @Francesco: if you're getting a `List<Monthly_Report>` from `GetSpecificYTMReport()' why shouldn't it work?

Comment: pardon it works. May you explain me why you instanciate the object inside the if and not when you declare it?

Answer (score 2):

The first line of code

```
var lprod_monthlyReport = new List<Monthly_Report>;
```

means that the variable is of type `List<Monthly_Report>` so it cannot contain a single `Monthly_Report` object.

This code should be refactored to work differently or have that one method return a `List<Monthly_Report>` with only one `Monthly_Report` in it.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Notice that the two methods are different. One returns a **List<Monthly_Report>** the other a **Monthly_Report**

Answer (score 1):

The important thing about the `var` keyword is that it doesn't mean "variant". `var` is used for type inference by the compiler, which means where you declare:

```
var something = new List<Something>();
```

...you are declaring something to be of type `List<Something>`. This means you can't then do:

```
something = new Something();
```

... as you've already declared it as something else. `var` from a usability perspective is syntactic sugar. The compiler (and the Visual Studio intellisense engine) are using type inference to know that `something` is actually `List<Something>`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to work, alas.

But you could as alternative wrap the single instance into a list if you wanted. Then you only have to make your code deal with a `List<Monthly_Report>` of either one or more `Monthly_Report` items.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
List<Monthly_Report> lprod_monthlyReport;

if (ytm == true) 
{
    lprod_monthlyReport = _ProductRep.GetSpecificArchiveReport(prod.Prod_ID, lmonth, lyear, item.item_ID);
} 
else
{ 
   lprod_monthlyReport = new List<Monthly_Report>() 
    {
       _ProductRep.GetSpecificYTMReport(prod.Prod_ID, item.item_ID)
    };
}
```

Comment: that won't compile, you can't assing the type of a `var` later.

Comment: thanks for your answer. However, you cannot declare a var variable without making an assignment.

Answer (score 0):

declare `lprod_monthlyReport` as an 'object'. There is no `is` relationship between `Monthly_Report` and `List<Monthly_Report>`.

You will have issues when you come to use the 'lprod_monthlyReport' because you won't know what type it is, other than object, the 'is' keyword could help you then.

Consider that and think about restructuring your code.

Comment: not applicable because then I need to query the variables. If I declare them as object the compiler won't find the querying methods